To display customers who have made a large number of orders in a certain time range for all time in SQL
There is a database with online store customers, which has the following data:

id buyer's;
order number;
date and time of the order;
order amount.

Data on customers and orders for 3 months.
How to withdraw customers who made more than 1 order per day and in the range of 3 hours of any day.
Is it possible to do this with a single query, or is it necessary to check each three-hour range manually?
For example, the buyer id 10321630 made 5 orders, on May 26, in the period from 19:00 to 22:00 (19:15, 19:37, 19:51, 21:07, 21:18) It is necessary that it be in the output of the query result.
I found tips on the Internet only about "between", but this is not exactly the case

Can you be more precise? Do you want to know if the customer made any two orders within 3hrs of each other, or is there a specific 3hr window you want to look at? What happens if they are within 3hrs of each other but over midnight? Do you need to see all those orders, or all of the orders such a customer made, or just the customer's ID?

@Charlieface,
or is there a specific 3hr window you want to look at?
Yes. There is no specific time, there is a 3 o'clock window itself, but it can be 3, 4 or 5 o'clock, it is not so important.
What happens if they are within 3hrs of each other but over midnight?
They should also fall if they fall into the three-hour window, but here I see the difficulty, I will add to the P.S. of the question.
Do you need to see all those orders..
Yes, need to look at all these orders.

Sorry that sounds contradictory. Are you saying you have a specific start time, and it continues for 3hrs (but that start time is variable) or are you saying you don't care what time that window starts at all for any particular customer, just that the orders fall within 3hrs of each other for that customer? Proper sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Say a single customer placed orders on the same date at  was placed at 9:30AM, 10:00AM, 1:00PM, 2:00PM and 3:00PM.  would the 1:PM order include the 10:00AM, 2 and 3 PM but then that's a 6 hour window.  How does the 3 hour "range" work?  is it before and after or just before or just after?

The challenge here is that every order has to be evaluated for a count of orders within that 3 hour range (I don't know if it is before or after or both yet)   so each order needs it's own count for other orders that fall within the 3 hour range.  Then; once find orders which have a count of 3 or greater, then we need to return the orders making up that count; but without knowing how your "range" works...

BETWEEN is the case. You can apply it to the ::time of what I'm guessing is your purchase timestamp: demo at db<>fiddle
select buyer_id
     , placed_at::date as placed_date
     , count(*) as number_of_orders
     , array_agg(placed_at::time(0)) as order_times
from orders 
where placed_at::time between '19:00' 
                          and '22:00' 
group by 1,2 
having count(*)>1;




buyer_id
placed_date
number_of_orders
order_times




10321630
2024-05-26
5
{19:15:00,21:18:00,21:07:00,19:51:00,19:37:00}


10321633
2024-06-15
2
{19:29:19,20:07:55}



If you mean any continuous 3-hour period within any one day, not the specific times between 19:00 and 20:00 from your example, it's a bit trickier: you'll need a stepping/rolling/tumbling count, which means using count(*) as a window function to restrict it to counting things up to 3 hours prior to any row.
select distinct on(1,2,order_times[1]) * from (
select buyer_id
     , placed_at::date as placed_date
     , count(*)over w1 as number_of_orders
     , array_agg(placed_at::time(0))over w1 as order_times
from orders 
window w1 as (partition by buyer_id,placed_at::date
              order by placed_at::time
              range between '3 hours' preceding
                        and current row))_
where number_of_orders>1
order by 1,2,order_times[1],number_of_orders desc;




buyer_id
placed_date
number_of_orders
order_times




10321630
2024-05-26
5
{19:15:00,19:37:00,19:51:00,21:07:00,21:18:00}


10321633
2024-06-15
2
{19:29:19,20:07:55}


10321630
2024-06-10
2
{10:06:42,11:35:34}


10321630
2024-06-11
2
{13:48:25,16:42:21}



Problem with that is you might get overlaps, some of which you can get rid of using the distinct on above, to only keep the maximum period spanning from a common point, instead of listing all its sub-periods.
If you have one order at midnight, another one at 2:59 and another one at 4:58, the middle one will show up once paired up with midnight and another time paired up with 4:58.

Using lag() is an easy option.
with dataX as (
    select *,
        lag(OrderTimestamp) over (
            partition by BuyerId
            order by OrderTimestamp) as lastOrderTimestamp
    from T
)
select *
from dataX
where lastOrderTimestamp >= OrderTimestamp - interval '3 hours'
order by BuyerId, OrderTimestamp;

Based on my reading of question and comments I don't think OP wants to constrain to a single date. Any order within three hours of a prior order would qualify for output regardless of which three-hour block it could be associated with. This will simply list them all rather than aggregating into any bundles. It seems to me that orders placed in close proximity need to be investigated because it's a bit unusual and this is a one-off, manual task.

It won't produce OP's example result as it only pairs up orders up to 3h apart, only two at a time. It's also only listing the buyers without the order info.

@Zegarek I think listing out all the data is what OP needs. That was a minor edit.

this query will return what you want but I wrote it for MYSQL
select buyer_id, count(id), group_concat(DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%H:%i:%s'))
from orders
where HOUR(order_date) BETWEEN 19 AND 22
group by buyer_id, DATE(order_date)
having count(*) > 1

the idea is grouping by buyer_id and the day of the order_date(without time)
